# How to create a generic integer-to-hex function for all Integer types?

Tags: generics, swift

I want to create an Integer-to-Hex function for all integer types.

For 1-byte Int8, it returns two letters, eg 0A

For 2-byte Int16, it returns four letters, eg 0A0B

for 8-byte Int64, it returns 16 letters, eg, 0102030405060708

```
func hex(v: Int) -> String {
    var s = ""
    var i = v
    for _ in 0..&lt;sizeof(Int)*2 {
        s = String(format: "%x", i & 0xF) + s
        i = i >> 4
    }
    return s
}

func hex(v: Int64) -> String {
    var s = ""
    var i = v
    for _ in 0..&lt;sizeof(Int64)*2 {
        s = String(format: "%x", i & 0xF) + s
        i = i >> 4
    }
    return s
}

func hex(v: Int32) -> String {
    var s = ""
    var i = v
    for _ in 0..&lt;sizeof(Int32)*2 {
        s = String(format: "%x", i & 0xF) + s
        i = i >> 4
    }
    return s
}

func hex(v: Int16) -> String {
    var s = ""
    var i = v
    for _ in 0..&lt;sizeof(Int16)*2 {
        s = String(format: "%x", i & 0xF) + s
        i = i >> 4
    }
    return s
}

func hex(v: Int8) -> String {
    var s = ""
    var i = v
    for _ in 0..&lt;sizeof(Int8)*2 {
        s = String(format: "%x", i & 0xF) + s
        i = i >> 4
    }
    return s
}
```

The above code works fine.

I then tried to create a generic version like this:

```
func hex<T: IntegerType>(v: T) -> String {
    var s = ""
    var i = v
    for _ in 0..<sizeof(T)*2 {
        s = String(format: "%x", i & 0xF) + s
        i = i >> 4
    }
    return s
}
```

When compiling this code, I got the error: T is not convertible to Int

What is the correct way to achieve this task?

Comment: Why don't you just use `String(radix:)`? Does the result that it gives seem so wrong? Added an answer suggesting this. Unfortunately your question does not include test data and desired results so it is difficult to guess precisely what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple solution is to coalesce the input value into `IntMax` with `.toIntMax()`.:

```
func hex<T: IntegerType>(v: T) -> String {
    var s = ""
    var i = v.toIntMax()
    for _ in 0..<sizeof(T)*2 {
        s = String(format: "%x", i & 0xF) + s
        i >>= 4
    }
    return s
}
```

Note: This works with only `0...Int64.max` values.

---

But, I would do:

```
func hex<T: IntegerType>(v: T) -> String {
    return String(format:"%0\(sizeof(T) * 2)x", v.toIntMax())
}
```

Note: This works with only `0...UInt32.max` values.

---

**Added:** This works with *all* available integer types/values.

```
func hex<T:IntegerType>(var v:T) -> String {
    var s = ""
    for _ in 0..<sizeof(T) * 2 {
        s = String(format: "%X", (v & 0xf).toIntMax()) + s
        v /= 16
    }
    return s
}
```

- `.toIntMax()` to cast `T` to concrete integer type.
- `/ 16` instead of `>> 4`.

Comment: This solution seems to be fine, but actually doesn't work because the String format API itself is buggy. It won't work with negative Int8 and Int16 types.  For example the line below will output ffffff80 instead of the expected 80:    

println(String(format: "%x", Int8.min))

The same problem exists for Int16.   I think this is a bug in the String formatting API.

Comment: That's why I noted: it works with `0...UInt32.max` values only. Added another solution.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear from your question why you are not using the built-in initializer that already does this for you:

```
let i = // some kind of integer
var s = String(i, radix:16)
```

If you don't like the resulting format of `s`, it is surely a lot easier to uppercase it and pad it out with extra characters than to go through all the work you're doing here.

Comment: While you’re right about this code duplicating that feature, the question was more about why the code doesn’t translate to a generic equivalent rather than the functionality itself.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity You may take the question that way, but I don't. I mean, I do think that question is _also_ interesting. (And I originally answered that question in a comment.) But as a practical matter, I feel that it is the job of the philosopher who sees a man trying to break through a wall to show him the already open door.

Comment: True but since they bust through the wall already and are now asking how to turn the hole into a nice archway, seems a bit harsh to point out the door that was already there...

Comment: But your answer is not getting the OP anywhere. My answer accomplishes the goal: turn a number into a hex string. I see no evidence that the OP even _knows_ that this feature is built into Swift already. Are you saying I shouldn't tell him?

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity I mean, the question was: "create an Integer-to-Hex function for all integer types". The String initializer does exactly that. I'm suggesting that the OP should build his function out of it. How on earth is that a wrong answer?

Comment: Ok fair point, really I guess it’s two questions, two faces *and* a vase :-)

Comment: Use String(i, radix:16) doesn't seem to be a good solution.  First, it outputs a minus sign for negative numbers. Secondly, you need to pad differently for negative and positive numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that while `>>` is defined for all the integer types, `IntegerType` does not guarantee its presence.  `IntegerType` conforms to `IntegerArithmeticType`, which gives you `+`, `-` etc., and `BitwiseOperationsType`, which gives you `&`, `|` etc.  But it doesn't look like `>>` is in either of them.

Bit of a bodge, but you could extend the integers with a new protocol, let's say `Shiftable`, and then require that:

```
protocol Shiftable {
    func >>(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    // + other shifting operators
}

extension Int: Shiftable {
  // nothing actually needed here
}

extension Int16: Shiftable { } // etc

// still need IntegerType if you want to do other operations
// (or alternatively Shiftable could require IntegerType conformance)
func shiftIt<I: protocol<IntegerType, Shiftable>>(i: I) {
    println(i+1 >> 4)
}

shiftIt(5000)
shiftIt(5000 as Int16)
```

edit: oop, looks like similar troubles with `String(format: ...)`, here is the best I could come up with:

edit2: as @rintaro ponts `.toIntMax()` is a way simpler solution to this, but it kinda takes the fun out of figuring out how to make it work totally generically :-)

```
func hex<T: protocol<IntegerType,Shiftable>>(v: T) -> String {

    // In creating this dictionary, the IntegerLiterals should
    // be converted to type T, which means you can use a type
    // T to look them up.  Hopefully the optimizer will only
    // run this code once per version of this function...
    let hexVals: [T:Character] = [
        0:"0", 1:"1", 2:"2", 3:"3", 4:"4",
        5:"5", 6:"6", 7:"7", 8:"8", 9:"9",
        10:"A", 11:"B", 12:"C", 13:"D", 14:"E", 15:"F"
    ]

    var chars: [Character] = []
    var i = v
    for _ in 0..<sizeof(T)*2 {
        chars.append(hexVals[(i & 0xF)] ?? "?")
        i = i >> 4
    }
    return String(lazy(chars).reverse())
}
```

Comment: Originally I tried this code, but got error: Extra argument 'format' in call

    func hex<T: IntegerType>(v: T) -> String {
 
        let fmt = "%0\(sizeof(T)*2)x"
  
        return String(format: fmt, v)
  
    }

Comment: Yeah I can’t see the definition of `String(format:)`, I’m guessing it’s pulled in by `Foundation.NSString`.  But I’d guess the `…` parameters are of type `AnyObject` and you can’t cast a `T: IntegerType` to an `AnyObject`.  You could try something like `var chars: [Character] = []` then `chars.append(first(toString(i & 0xF))!)` in the loop and `return String(reverse(chars))`.

Comment: duh no what am I thinking that won’t give you a hex digit. hmm no trivial solution to that that I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the input.

The first version of the generic functions I created was:

```
func hex<T: UnsignedIntegerType>(v: T) -> String {
    var fmt = "%0\(sizeof(T)*2)"
    fmt += (sizeof(T) > 4) ? "llx" : "x"
    return String(format: fmt, v.toUIntMax())
}

func hex<T: SignedIntegerType>(v: T) -> String {
    var fmt = "%0\(sizeof(T)*2)"
    fmt += (sizeof(T) > 4) ? "llx" : "x"
    return String(format: fmt, v.toIntMax())
}
```

I used the following code to test the two functions

```
println("=== 64-bit ===")
println(hex(UInt64.max))
println(hex(UInt64.min))
println(hex(Int64.max))
println(hex(Int64.min))

println("=== 32-bit ===")
println(hex(UInt32.max))
println(hex(UInt32.min))
println(hex(Int32.max))
println(hex(Int32.min))

println("=== 16-bit ===")
println(hex(UInt16.max))
println(hex(UInt16.min))
println(hex(Int16.max))
println(hex(Int16.min))

println("=== 8-bit ===")
println(hex(UInt8.max))
println(hex(UInt8.min))
println(hex(Int8.max))
println(hex(Int8.min))
```

The output for 16-bit and 8-bit negative integers is apparently wrong.

```
=== 64-bit ===
ffffffffffffffff
0000000000000000
7fffffffffffffff
8000000000000000
=== 32-bit ===
ffffffff
00000000
7fffffff
80000000
=== 16-bit ===
ffff
0000
7fff
ffff8000
=== 8-bit ===
ff
00
7f
ffffff80
```

This is caused by the %x specifier, which expects 32-bit integers only.  It generates wrong output for negative Int8 and Int16.

```
String(format: '%x', Int16.min)   // outputs ffff8000
String(format: '%x', Int8.min)    // outputs ffffff80
```

The second approach is to use the bitwise operators instead:

```
func hex<T: SignedIntegerType>(v: T) -> String {
    var s = ""
    var i = v.toIntMax()
    for _ in 0..<sizeof(T)*2 {
        s = String(format: "%x", i & 0xF) + s
        i = i >> 4
    }
    return s
}

func hex<T: UnsignedIntegerType>(v: T) -> String {
    var s = ""
    var i = v.toUIntMax()
    for _ in 0..<sizeof(T)*2 {
        s = String(format: "%x", i & 0xF) + s
        i = i >> 4
    }
    return s
}
```

So far, they seem to work fine for all integers, negative and positive.  The test code outputs:

```
=== 64-bit ===
ffffffffffffffff
0000000000000000
7fffffffffffffff
8000000000000000
=== 32-bit ===
ffffffff
00000000
7fffffff
80000000
=== 16-bit ===
ffff
0000
7fff
8000
=== 8-bit ===
ff
00
7f
80
```

Comment: There is a better answer here.  You may wish to mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution as a Swift 2 protocol extension method,
using the print width modifier constants from `<inttypes.h>`:

```
extension IntegerType where Self: CVarArgType {
    var hex : String {
        let format : String
        switch (sizeofValue(self)) {
        case 1:
            format = "%02" + __PRI_8_LENGTH_MODIFIER__ + "X"
        case 2:
            format = "%04" + PRIX16
        case 4:
            format = "%08" + PRIX32
        case 8:
            format = "%016" + __PRI_64_LENGTH_MODIFIER__ + "X"
        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected integer size")
        }
        return String(format: format, self)
    }
}
```

This works correctly for the full range of all signed and unsigned
integer types:

```
UInt8.max.hex // FF
Int8.max.hex  // 7F
Int8.min.hex  // 80

UInt16.max.hex // FFFF
Int16.max.hex  // 7FFF
Int16.min.hex  // 8000

UInt32.max.hex // FFFFFFFF
Int32.max.hex  // 7FFFFFFF
Int32.min.hex  // 80000000

UInt64.max.hex // FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Int64.max.hex  // 7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Int64.min.hex  // 8000000000000000
```

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
extension Integer where Self: CVarArg {
    var hex : String {
        let format : String
        switch MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: self) {
        case 1:
            format = "%02" + __PRI_8_LENGTH_MODIFIER__ + "X"
        case 2:
            format = "%04" + PRIX16
        case 4:
            format = "%08" + PRIX32
        case 8:
            format = "%016" + __PRI_64_LENGTH_MODIFIER__ + "X"
        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected integer size")
        }
        return String(format: format, self)
    }
}
```