# Failing to implement Protocol Extension for conforming type

Tags: swift, generics, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

*(feel free to retitle question as appropriate)*

I'm working with a lot of BLE data, and for debugging purposes, I've found it easy to extend `UInt8` with a `HEX` computed variable:

```
extension UInt8 {
    var HEX:String {
        return String(format: "%02X", self)
    }
}

// 190.HEX --> "BE"
```

I found myself wanting a lowercase variant. And then I wanted it for `UInt32` and `UInt16` as well. Since the only thing that changes is the number of digits to print, I thought I could do this with a protocol of sorts (at least for education purposes).

```
protocol HexPrintable {
    var hexDigitCount:Int { get }
}

extension UInt8:HexPrintable {
    var hexDigitCount:Int {
        return 2
    }
}

extension UInt16:HexPrintable {
    var hexDigitCount:Int {
        return 4
    }
}

extension UInt32:HexPrintable {
    var hexDigitCount:Int {
        return 8
    }
}
```

Then comes the part where I want to take advantage of this and provide default implementations of the `HEX` and `hex` methods:

```
extension HexPrintable {
    var HEX:String {
        return String(format: "%0\(self.hexDigitCount)X", self)
    }

    var hex:String {
        return String(format: "%0\(self.hexDigitCount)x", self)
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error `Argument type 'Self' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArgType'`.

I think I understand this. It's saying that as a protocol, it can't guarantee that adopting types will be of a type (`CVarArgType`) that could be used in the String initializer like that. So I thought I could use a `where` clause for the first time. I modified my protocol extension to look like:

```
extension HexPrintable where Self == CVarArgType { ...
```

Which leads to a `Same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'Self' non-generic`. At which point my amateur type theorist understanding overflowed. What is the magic to make my two extension methods on different UInt sizes work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be

```
extension HexPrintable where Self : CVarArgType { ... }
```

Alternatively, make your `HexPrintable` protocol inherit from `CVarArgType`:

```
protocol HexPrintable : CVarArgType {
    var hexDigitCount:Int { get }
}
```

Note that you can implement the same functionality
with a single extension on `IntegerType`, using `sizeofValue()`
to determine the output width:

```
extension IntegerType where Self : CVarArgType {
    var HEX : String {
        let size = sizeofValue(self)
        return String(format: "%0\(2*size)X", self)
    }
}
```

But there is another problem: The `%X` format expects a `Int32` argument
(corresponding to the C `int` type). Both your and my above code will 
not produce correct results for values exceeding the range of a 32-bit
integer.

Various possible solutions to that problem are given e.g. in
[How to create a generic integer-to-hex function for all Integer types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640198/how-to-create-a-generic-integer-to-hex-function-for-all-integer-types) (and I just added another
one).

Comment: Cool. This is certainly simpler than what I was trying. Was what I was trying even technically possible though? I'd like to understand the errors I was seeing better...

Comment: Ahh... so it was just the `==` bit. Is the `==` in a where clause actually legitimate syntax which means something else then?

Comment: @TravisGriggs: Usually `==` is used for type equality, and `:` for conformance to a protocol. But it seems to be more complicated, e.g. `extension SequenceType where Self.Generator.Element == Int {}`  compiles, but `extension Array where Self.Element == Int {}` does not compile :) – Anyway, there  is a problem with both your and my code, I will update the answer in a moment.